# Did Spock ever say "impressive, Captain"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

I have a memory of seeing Spock say the line "Impressive, Captain", but now I can't locate where that was.  Am I misremembering this?

Comment: Are fanfics acceptable? :) http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Farchiveofourown.org%2Fworks%2F120856&ei=wLOuVLb3EIaJuwS314HgAQ&usg=AFQjCNHDOOue4vvVWkL599-OtsriY5L1ig&sig2=KSxOHER9StZ1Iu-7pmbSeg&bvm=bv.83339334,d.c2E

Comment: You may be getting memories mixed around. I believe the line was in TNG and was directed at Captain PICARD, not Kirk.

Comment: You could be confusing Kirk with that other great starship captain, Major-General-Webelos Zapp Brannigan. He describes Turanga Leela as "one impressive piece of Captain" once.

Answer (score 4):

In a discussion between Spock and Kirk, ["Unquestionably. Most impressive."](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0001439/quotes) is the closest quote I could find...

Comment: I looked at the context of your quote, and it's not what I'm remembering, because in your quote, Spock is saying that he's impressed with something external.  What I'm remembering is a *compliment* by Spock to Kirk... i.e. Spock is impressed with something Kirk did or said.

Comment: @JoelFan Ah I see. Sorry I couldn't be of help!

Answer (score 4):

There was one instance of that exact phrase in non-canon licensed books, but it wasn't Spock speaking.

[*Star Trek: Signature Edition: Worlds in Collision*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743485092) By Judith Reeves-Stevens:

> **Very Impressive, Captain.** I would have sworn you had tuned me out completely. ([src](https://books.google.com/books?id=eYQHpDSf30gC&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=spock%20%22impressive,%20Captain%22&source=bl&ots=epQ-NykKYL&sig=MQcjX8AmR4TSrhkAAFXmS7FfBK0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wLOuVLb3EIaJuwS314HgAQ&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=spock%20%22impressive%2C%20Captain%22&f=false))

---

There didn't seem to be any phrase exactly like that [in TOS episode transcripts](https://www.google.com/search?q=spock%20%22impressive%2C%20Captain%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&q=site:www.chakoteya.net%20%22impressive%2C%20Captain%22%20), though it did occur in one TNG episode.

However, there were several quotes that were somewhat similar in nature:

> SPOCK: Unquestionably. Most impressive. (*Spectre Of The Gun*)

.

> SPOCK [OC]: If I may explain, Captain. She refers to the tape storehouse of knowledge of the builders of this place. I scan it. **A most impressive store.**

Kirk himself said something similar in a couple of episodes.

Comment: How did you dig that up?? Very impressive.

Comment: That wasn't Spock though. Looking at the Google books excerpt you gave, it looks like the speaker of that line is [Mira Romaine](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Mira_Romaine).

Comment: @Daft I came across that line & book myself by googling "Impressive Captain" combined with "Star Trek".

Comment: @TrishLing I added "Spock" to my search. I can see you have discovered it was actually Mira Romaine that said it and not Spock, which is probably why I didn't find it.

Comment: @TrishLing - good point. Updated